# Problem with executing google app script (google slides) after renaming presentation and script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm quite new to programming and using google apps scripts.
I wrote script that splits selected text in text box (google slides) in different text boxes (each line of initial textbox is a separated textbox). Code was just a modification of examples from developers.google.com.

```
function SelectedTextGrabber() {
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  var selectionType = selection.getSelectionType();
  var currentPage;
  switch (selectionType) {
  case SlidesApp.SelectionType.NONE:
    Logger.log('Nothing selected');
    break;
...
case SlidesApp.SelectionType.TEXT:
    var tableCellRange = selection.getTableCellRange();
    if (tableCellRange != null) {
      var tableCell = tableCellRange.getTableCells()[0];
      Logger.log('Selected text is in a table at row ' +
                 tableCell.getRowIndex() + ', column ' +
                 tableCell.getColumnIndex());
    }
    var textRange = selection.getTextRange();
    if (textRange.getStartIndex() == textRange.getEndIndex()) {
      Logger.log('Text cursor position: ' + textRange.getStartIndex());
    } else {
      Logger.log('Selection is a text range from: ' + textRange.getStartIndex() + ' to: ' +
                 textRange.getEndIndex() + ' is selected');
      var s1 = textRange.asString();
      var s2 = '';
      var s3 = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
        if (s1[i] === '\n' || i === s1.length -1) {
            s3.push(s2);
            s2='';
        } else {
          s2 += s1[i];
        }
    }
// textbox parameteres
      var h4 = 0;
      var left = 10;
      var top = 10;
      var textsize = 12;
      var standnum = 37;
      var width = 2 * textsize + (textsize - textsize % 2) / 2 * standnum;
      Logger.log(width);

      var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[1];
      for (var i = 0; i < s3.length; i++){
        //анализ размера текстового блока
        var s4 = s3[i].length;
        if (s4 <= standnum) {
        h4 = textsize * 2;
        } else {
          h4 = textsize * 2 + (s4 - s4 % standnum) / standnum * textsize;
        }
        var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, left, top, width, h4);
        var textRange = shape.getText();
        textRange.setText(s3[i]);
        textRange.getTextStyle().setFontSize(textsize);
        top += h4;
        if (top > 370) {
        top = 10;
        left += width;  
        }
      }
    }
    break;
  case SlidesApp.SelectionType.TABLE_CELL:
    var tableCells = selection.getTableCellRange().getTableCells();
    var table = tableCells[0].getParentTable();
    Logger.log('There are ' + tableCells.length + ' table cells selected.');
    break;
  case SlidesApp.SelectionType.PAGE:
    var pages = selection.getPageRange().getPages();
    Logger.log('There are ' + pages.length + ' pages selected.');
    break;
  default:
    break;
}

}
```

It worked just fine, but **when I renamed script and presentation, I get the TypeError: Cannot call method "getSelectionType" of null. (line 4, file "Code").**

After 30 minutes of waiting this script started working again without errors.
I thought it may happen because it takes time to make some changes in google servers.
But when I modified initial text in text box to be splitted the script gave me the same result as I didn't change initial text (the result is separated lines in textboxes but for initial text).
Do u have any idea what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm trying your code and is not working for me in a sample slide. Could you please provide a sample slides in which you have tested your code?

Comment: Raserhin, thank you for trying help me! As you can see in the code, you have to select the text (Ctrl(Cmd)+A) in the textbox to make it work. Also you can see "..." in Line 9. I wrote it to make the code shorter.  Just delete these ellipses (...)

Comment: Have you modified your slide between name edits. For me the error you got seems to be when I try to get a nonexistent slide. This line of code will return null if you don't have a second slide 
`var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[1];` in my case it was returning a `null` value (remember is 0-based array). After that I've tried to change the name of the slide multiple times and didn't work. Also [`getActivePresentation()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#getactivepresentation) could return a `null` value.

Comment: Talking about the presentation it's nothing special. I created one with two slides, put the textbox to be splitted on the second slide, 'cause the first slide is title basically. According to the code I put splitted text boxes on the second slide. Sorry that I didn't mention it before.